# How Can I Understand Eloquent orderBy() Works?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Please help me understand how orderBy works. Look at the following code.

`$posts = Post::orderBy('title','asc')->get();`

When I use `orderBy('title','asc')` does it mean I receive all of the Post records and put them into

`$posts` and then order them by title ascending? I'm confused with `orderBy()`. I remember

when we want to receive all the records we should type "all" after Post so how does `orderBy()` do that?

Comment: You will receive all your posts ordered by their title in ascending order.

Comment: Use `all()` when you're not adding anything to the query otherwise you would use `get()`.

Comment: it works according to their alpahbetic or numeric numbering in whatsoever way specified e.g. if great, angry,deduce are to be ordered asc it would be angry,dedduce then great

Comment: orderBy happens in database layer , and sorted result will be stored in the `$post`

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, orderBy method allows you to sort the result of the query by a given column. 
If using orderBy  your query should look like:

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('title','asc')->get();
```

When using all() you query would be:

```
$posts = Post::all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's exactly what you said.

> The orderBy method allows you to sort the result of the query by a given column. The first argument to the orderBy method should be the column you wish to sort by, while the second argument controls the direction of the sort and may be either asc or desc:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
                ->get();
```

Take a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) to see more info about this